# readFromParcel() method in Parcelable interface

Tags: android, android-service, parcelable, aidl

I have a simple doubt in marshaling during service creation. When there is a `writeToParcel()` method declared in `Parcelable` interface which is invoked in stub generated (if aidl method parameters are declared as `in`), why there is no `readFromParcel()` declaration in `Parcelable` interface(for `out` parameters)?

I can create my own `readFromParcel()` but as per my understanding there should be a overridden `readFromParcel()` declaration in Parcelable interface if the generated stub wants to invoke it. But the documentation for [Parcelable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) does not show any sign of `readFromParcel()` method. Why is it so? Was it included in previous API version and later got removed? Please explain !

And how different is createFromParcel() from readFromParcel() if both tries to read a parcelable object and populate member fields with the data out of it?

Comment: `readFromParcel` requires a pre-created object whereas `createFromParcel` returns a newly instantiated object straight from the parcel. This is because when a `Parcelable` type instance is used as an `out` or `inout` parameter, conceptually the Binder subsystem creates an empty object first, and then fills it in with `readFromParcel` when the response is returned.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have declared a parameter of that type as "inout" in your AIDL.

When returned from the method, generated AIDL proxy will call `readFromParcel()` to update the parameter value (as defined by the "inout" qualifier).

Comment: The question may be incorrectly worded, but I believe this answers it correctly. There is no `readFromParcel` in the interface probably cos not everyone needs their `Parcelable` to be an `out` or `inout` parameter. This could have been solved by making Parcelable an abstract class (or if  Android moves to Java 8, with a default method).

Answer (score 2):

`createFromParcel` is exactly what it sounds like.  A NEW Intance of the parcelable Object/Class that has been written to parcel : `Parcelable.writeToParcel()` is created.  This is a good thing, as it helps prevent memory leaks, as you are not holding on to a reference to the object from another class that may or may not have been destroyed

Comment: What about readFromParcel? Why is it being invoked as part of the stub generated? Any insights ?

Comment: Typically you call it from the constructor.. not sure i understand your question

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [Parcelable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) :

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };

 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }
}
```

When an object of a class which implements the Parcelable interface is to be written to a Parcel, `writeToParcel(...)` is called.

When an object of this class is to be created using a Parcel, `CREATOR.createFromParcel(Parcel in)` is called. From there onwards, how the class creates its instance from the Parcel is upto the developer of the class. In the above example, a constructor `private MyParcelable(Parcel in)` is called from the `createFromParcel(...)` method.

Conventionally, many developers define a `readFromParcel(Parcel in)` method in their implementations and call it from the constructor:

```
 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     readFromParcel(in);
 }

 private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }
```